# pandas: how to check for repeated values in one column and create a pairwise list of values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Out[2]: 
          A         B
0       200         5
2       100        11
4       200         3
6       300         6
8       300         9
10      200         4
```

I would like to be able to check for repeated values in column A (here the 200 & 300 are repeated) and then output a list of pairwise values from the values in column B which are on the same rows as the repeated values in column A, as follows:

[(5,3), (5,4), (3,4), (6,9)]

The order of the numbers in the tuples doesn't matter, i.e. (5,3) is as good as (3,5).

How would I do this please?

Comment: Could you please explain how the output is related to the input DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same as cphlewis, but using Pandas:

```
>>> df
     A   B
0  200   5
1  100  11
2  200   3
3  300   6
4  300   9
5  200   4
>>> import itertools as it
>>> [list(it.combinations(t[1:][0], 2)) for t in df.groupby('A').B if len(t[1:][0])>1]
[[(5, 3), (5, 4), (3, 4)], [(6, 9)]]
```

Since `it.combinations(t[1:][0], 2)` and `df.groupby('A').B` are both iterators, you probably would want to write something like this to be more memory friendly:

```
def combo(df):
    for t in df.groupby('A').B:
        if len(t[1:][0])>1:
             yield it.combinations(t[1:][0], 2)
```

Which will yield each group of combinations in turn and not generate them all at once.

Comment: Thanks to both cphlewis and dawg for your responses. dawg, I'm using your solution in my code and it works brilliantly!

Comment: The way I wrote this was primarily for demo -- be sure to optimize since both `df.groupby('A').B` and `it.combinations(t[1:][0], 2)` are iterators and only calculated as accessed.  It the solution was helpful, please consider accepting the answer but clicking the check mark on the left...

Comment: Also, check the timing -- in the test case I ran the _explicit_ version is faster. (Zen of Python, explicit is better than implicit.)

Answer (score 1):

Timer set up for comparisons over a range of data sizes:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import timeit

size = 100
setup = '''
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint

size = %s

rv = pd.DataFrame(randint(0, high=9, size=(size,2)), columns=['A','B'])
rvg = rv.groupby('A')


def explicit(rvg):
    total = []
    for k, v in rvg.B:
        if len(v)> 1:
            total.append(list(itertools.combinations(v, 2)))
    return total


def listcomp(rvg):
    return [list(itertools.combinations(v[1:][0], 2)) for v in rvg.B if len(v[1:][0])>1]

'''
for size in (100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000):
    print('%d records:'%size)
    print('Explicit loop: '),
    print(min(timeit.Timer('explicit(rvg)', setup=setup%size).repeat(7, 1000)))
    print('Implicit loop: '),
    print(min(timeit.Timer('listcomp(rvg)', setup=setup%size).repeat(7, 1000)))
'''
# to verify that they give the same results
print(explicit(rvg))
print('\n')
print(listcomp(rvg))
'''
```

implicit eventually is faster:

> ```
> 100 records:
> Explicit loop:  1.04004383087
> Implicit loop:  1.04814505577
> 500 records:
> Explicit loop:  2.24344801903
> Implicit loop:  2.28265190125
> 1000 records:
> Explicit loop:  6.24254918098
> Implicit loop:  6.72238111496
> 5000 records:
> Explicit loop:  194.443366051
> Implicit loop:  194.122081041
> 10000 records:
> Explicit loop:  778.750103951
> Implicit loop:  777.272083044
> ```

Comparing to dawg's generator version is left as an exercise for someone else.

Comment: Thank you, cphlewis.  The DataFrame I'm working on has more than 750,000 rows and probably somewhere around half of those contain repeated values in column A.  Therefore I was wondering if anyone had a "magic" bit of code that might be able to do the job for me in one line, without a "for" loop?

Comment: Time this answer against dawg's -- they both use `for`, but the list comprehension might optimize it.